# How can I fix div tags to fit perfectly side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to fit the two div tags side by side
I want to text to only go to 50% page width,
and image to be 50% page width.
I also do not want the image to be so large. just a normal size and will form to page size

Thank You!

**html**

```css
#hero .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hero .col-left {
  width: 50%;
}

#hero .col-right {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <div class="hero container">
    <div class="column-left column">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right column">
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` with `flex: 50%` on the flex-children.

```css
#hero {
  width: 100%;
}

.container { 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.column {
  flex: 50%;
}

.column-left {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#hero .col-left{
  width: 100%;
}
#hero .col-right{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
        <div class="hero container">
          <div class="column-left column">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <ul>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
              <li>test</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right column">fooooooooo
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: @nate this not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Flex defaults to a `flex-row` placing items in a row, so to put something side by side, you want to have them in a `flex-row` instead of `flex-column`. To size the image appropriately you have to set a width/height. To have the image scale, set the image `width` and `height` to take up whatever percentage of the available space. In this instance I just let the image take 100% of the space.

```css
#hero .container{
  display:flex;
}

#hero .col-left{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#hero .col-right{
  width: 50%;
}

#hero .col-right #eclipse {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <div class="hero container">
    <div class="col-left column">
      <h1>test</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right column">
      <img
      id="eclipse"
src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Solar_Eclipse_May_20%2C2012.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```